# Positioning multiple Divs with Flex trouble

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, position

I've been trying to get this right for a while now and haven't had any luck. I am trying to do this:

[image]

I am having a hard time getting the img's and text next to each other. I am using Position: Absolute and Position: Relative but I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please help me out. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is my code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong! (I put the borders on just to see where all the containers/divs start. It's for organization purposes and ill get rid of them after I fix this.) (I am also using Inline Styling)

```
...
<div style={{
          padding: "40px",
          width: "100vw",
          zIndex: "2"
        }}>
        <div
          className="container"
          style={{
            top: "50%",
            zIndex: "1",
          }}
        >
          <div className="row" style={{
              display: "flex",
              position: "relative",
              border: "green 5px solid"
          }}>
            <div className="col-sm-8">
              <img
                src="/Images/Img.JPG"
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  position: "absolute",
                  zIndex: "1"
                }}
              />
              <img
                src={OrangeBigSquare}
                style={{
                  width: "100%",
                  position: "absolute",
                  zIndex: "0",
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div
              className="col-sm-4"
              style={{
                alignItems: "center",
                display: "flex",
                position: "absolute",
                zIndex: "10",
                border: "blue 1px solid"
              }}
            >
              <h1>Hi, i'm Shane and sometimes I do things.</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a codepen or similar with your code please? That was supposed to be a comment, sorry.

Comment: I don't know how I would separate the inline styles into CSS and when where to put the Container/column/row. :(

Comment: Ok, I will try to make something on codepen.

Comment: Wow! let me know if i can provide anything that can help. thank you so much!

Comment: Hard to understand what you want and what doesn't work

Comment: Yeah no worries. I am trying to get the picture and the text to be next to each other. I am using a container/row/col with an 8/4 ratio. 8 - img, 4 - text. 
I am also trying to make it go side by side with flex. But neither of these options are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, did something super quick with flex here but I think you can get the idea:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-night-pr5p3i?file=/src/App.js

EDIT:

Improved version:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-browser-05lk97?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Note that by using px nor using media query, this is not responsive at all

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much!!! Youre the best!

Comment: @James, yes of course, just sketched something quick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think flex is the good option here. Since you want customize position, no meaning to change the `display` of the element.

This is an example to make what your desired result

```css
body{
margin:0;
background-color:grey;
}
img{
z-index:1;
width:50vw;
height:50vh;
position:absolute;
top:15%;
left:2%;
}
h1{
position:absolute;
left:55vw;
width:35vw;
top:20vh;
z-index:2;
line-height:1.5em;
font-size: calc(5vw );
text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/414102/pexels-photo-414102.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'>
<h1>Hi, i'm Shane and sometimes I do things.</h1>
```

Comment: Interesting, so you didnt use flex or bootstrap containers? Just straight CSS? And would you just @media in CSS to make it responsive?

Comment: @Shaneeyb, first it is responsive, because all the unit I used is either percentage or vw or vh (even font-size)which is based on screen size. The media query is always used when we want to hide/show specific element when screen size is too small/big. I don't think it is nessary here (at least the code you given)

Comment: @Shaneeyb, in term of `so you didnt use flex or bootstrap containers?` firstly, bootstrap is a framework/library to empower JS/css, diplay:flex is to change how elements displays. At least for me, I commonly used display;flex to change how several elements looks or make elements center, but here no. I think pure css is enough for this situtiion

Comment: Great! thanks for the heads up and suggestions! I appreciate it! It helps a ton!

Comment: @Shaneeyb, no problem, glad I could help:)